# How to use collections when define DataContract?

Tags: wcf

I want to 'send' collection that contain numbers ( double ).
I try to add array to my DataContract but its fail ( thru exception .. when i remark the array type its work fine ).

How can i do it ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection Serialization happens automatically only when the collection in the contract is a concrete collection (that is, not an interface) and is serializable (annotated with the Serializable attribute). If that is the case, WCF can automatically serialize the collection as an array of the collection’s type as long as the collection contains an Add operation. This holds true for both the built-in .NET collections and for any of your own custom collections that implement the IEnumerable or IEnumerable interface; as long as they are serializable and have an Add operation, they can be serialized to arrays automatically.

If your collection does not meet these constraints specify the CollectionDataContractAttribute.

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "MyCollectionOf{0}")]
```

Comment: I have a class marked with this CollectionDataContract attribute. But the enum in that class is not serialized. Any ideas??